# Error in `[.default`(object$tables[[v]], , nd) : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, rstudio, naivebayes

I have 22 variables (including 1 class variable)

So, i run the following code:

```
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(dataset$class, p=split, list=FALSE)
data_train <- dataset[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- dataset[-trainIndex,]
model <- NaiveBayes(class~., data=data_train)
data_train$class <- factor(data_train$class)
model <- NaiveBayes(class~., data=data_train)
x_test <- data_test[,1:21]
y_test <- data_test[,22]
```

it works so far, but whenever i try to did the following command:

```
predictions <- predict(model, x_test)
```

it shows the following error:

> Error in `[.default`(object$tables[[v]], , nd) : subscript out of bounds
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 2: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 3: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 4: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 5: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 6: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 7: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 8: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 9: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 10: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: What is this function "createDataPartition()" ? Also, would be good if you provide an example!

Comment: i am trying to do split by using the command >split=0.80

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva it's from the caret package. Ahmad, it's good practice to show the packages that you are using for a minimum reproducible example. Could you provide us with a sample of your data. Also, you should factor your data if it's numeric BEFORE you create a partition using `createPartition`. We don't know what the variable `split` is either. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example